# Shoes for a very heavy man?

Tags: shoes

I'm 330 lbs and 5'11 and I've a problem with my shoes, I wore them out to fast but from one side only, the outer side. So my ankle twist and that make my hip hurts, I change shoes frequently but the same thing happens all over again. Any specific specific features or characteristics I should look on a shoe?

Comment: You might want to visit an orthopedist, too, chances are that you need inlays or special shoes.

Comment: More an observation, but if the shoes wear out that quickly, perhaps minimal footwear would be a better alternative, because they don't try to (futilely) correct possibly abnormal movements. Unless you experience pain or problems when walking barefooted, I don't expect a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read this [page on how to select a running shoe](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/info/index.jsp?categoryId=12749426). Sounds like you underpronate your walk.  That is you walk slightly outward on your foot with each step.  From the chart on the page you might want to try a neutral type of shoe.

> Underpronation/Supination: The two terms "underpronation" and "supination" can be used interchangeably to describe a runner whose foot does not roll in at all or even rolls slightly outward with each step in the running gait. The runner pushes off mainly from the small toes on the outside of the foot. An extremely small percentage of the population underpronates. Typically, a runner with a high arch will underpronate. A runner with this foot mechanic will have extreme wear on the outside edge of his or her current running shoe. Underpronators generally need a NEUTRAL shoe that encourages a more natural inward foot motion. Shop our great assortment of men's and women's neutral running shoes.

Comment: Please quote important parts of the link and add them to your answer. Link only answers are not very useful, especially after [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: Honestly, there are hardly any shoes that tailor to supination, so in this specific case I don't think it will help the OP much. If the problem of excessive wearing occurs even with the toughest or most supportive shoe, the OP will either need orthotics or custom shoes or (dramatically) alter his running style. I put my 2 cents on the latter.

Comment: @dfdx2 Thank you! It's definitely the answer! I got myself some new shoes with your recomendation and it makes a hell of a difference!